# How do you disinfect a concert grand piano?

Tags: piano

I'm part of a group discussing the feasibility of running our regular Annual Music Festival next June. (Festival June 2020 was cancelled because of Covid). We're anticipating Covid is still going to be a major factor in any preparations. Here's one problem: in previous years the venue let us use their *beautiful* Fazioli grand piano. Would there be any way of safely disinfecting it with *no risk* of damaging it? I can't imagine wiping the keys with an alcohol wipe…

Comment: FYI: Just did a complete rewrite of my answer.

Comment: As an alternative to overcleaning the piano, is it an option to let the pianists wear gloves instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fazioli recommends](http://www.fazioli.com/en/news-events/how-clean-and-sanitize-keyboard-fazioli-pianos) a detergent/disinfectant solution or an alcohol solution of no more than 30% for their piano keyboards. The site includes an instructional video.

On other sites:

- Steinway [recommends hydrogen peroxide](https://www.steinway.com/news/features/utilty/cleaning-your-piano).
- The Piano Technicians Guild Piano [recommends disinfectant wipes](https://www.ptg.org/covid-19), as does [Piano Magazine](https://www.pianistmagazine.com/blogs/how-to-disinfect-your-piano/).

Comment: Would you care to explain why not to wipe with alcohol? It's so much simpler&quicker, more reliably kills viruses, and actually pretty harmless to both wood and the plastic on the keys (unlike UV light, which embrittles plastics – though it's unlikely to matter either – or water which as you say warps wood). Where alcohol shouldn't be used is near wood that has been treated with oil or delicate varnishes, particularly on string instruments, but that doesn't seem to apply to piano.

Comment: Pianos are heavily laquered. For that reason I've never used alcohol, even for the keys, and the online advice I've seen concurred. However, you prompted me to do another search, and Steinway is currently recommending hydrogen peroxide. I've updated the post.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Just did a complete rewrite. Advice had changes since the beginning of the pandemic.

Comment: 30% of alcohol seems low. For hand sanitizers typically at least 60% is required, and higher concentrations reduce the time necessary to deactivate the virus.