# If I need to play piano with gloves on, what type of glove will have minimal impact on my technique?

Tags: piano, technique

In a comment to [How do you disinfect a concert grand piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/106912/21766), ThisIsMe floated the idea of pianists wearing gloves while they play if disinfecting or overcleaning a piano becomes a problem.

I admit I hadn't considered using gloves, and not knowing how my own classroom teaching will be affected over the next several months, I'm curious:

What type of glove will have minimal impact on playing technique? I assume some gloves will slip off the keys too easily, but I assume other gloves may stick to the keys too much.

For those with this experience (anyone?) what type of glove would be best?

Comment: In addition it might make sense to consider other factors, such as sweat buildup, smell, and possible allergic reaction. A latex-free nitrile glove is probably the best choice despite the fact that it will likely feel like it sticks to the keys a bit.

Comment: Wipe the piano with an alcohol wipe, make the players use an alcohol sanitiser. Air transmission is high, surface transmission is low. Get people tested before they are allowed in. I'm currently being tested twice a week to be allowed to work.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to research what kind of glove a popular youtuber known as "Scott Bass Lessons" is wearing. Other things to consider are: do given gloves offer actual protection from virus, and prevent its spread? Can they be disinfected or washed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent an hour playing piano while wearing **Nitrile, Powder-Free, 4 Mil gloves**. I played snippets of a range of repertoire on an upright with plastic keytops and a grand with ivory keytops. Here are my observations.

#### Overall

- Some minor, initial difficulty **judging chord shapes** (probably due to resistance; see below), but not to the point of missing notes.
- The gloves were tight-fitting and **offered resistance** to even small hand opening/stretching. I could feel the effort in my hands from the outset.
- Plastic keys must be clean to prevent slipping.
- **Ivory keys "squeak"** when a gloved finger rubs against a key. Not loud, but noticeable to the player.
- I was playing in a cold room, and I am prone to cold hands. By the end of the hour (of fairly light playing), my hands had begun to **sweat**. A performer considering using these gloves in a warm room, in a higher pressure situation, or for a player prone to sweating, test them out first.
- Touch and **fast finger and rhythm control** was affected when **playing softly**, especially on the upright (which is harder to control even without gloves). In particular, the **key depth was difficult to judge** at first, and rapid, small finger movements were restricted enough to be noticeable.

#### Effect on Specific Techniques

Excepting the resistance of the gloves, here is what I found in actual pieces.

- Arpeggios: unaffected (Chopin Etudes 10/1 and 25/1; Schubert Impromptus 90/3 and 90/4)
- Repeated notes: unaffected (Rachmaninoff Prelude in G Minor 33/5)
- **Quiet playing**: slight difficulty with touch at first (Bach Prelude in C Major BWV 846; Schubert Impromptu 90/3)
- Left-hand leaps: unaffected (Joplin "Maple Leaf Rag")
- **Fast finger work**: difficult (Bach Prelude in C Minor BWV 847; Chopin 25/11 "Winter Wind")
- Finger exchange: unaffected (Bach Fugue in C Major BWV 846)
- Finger cross-over/-under (including 4-over-5 and 5-under-4): unaffected (Bach Fugue in C Major BWV 846)

---

EDIT:

Tried mittens.

Pros:

- Tone clusters very easy.
- Glissandos hurt less.

Cons:

- Everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about piano, but I had cracked skin / lesions on my fingers last winter and was surprised to find that I could easily play guitar chords and single note lines wearing cheap DIY gloves like [these ones](https://www.diy.com/departments/site-general-handling-gloves-large/3663602671527_BQ.prd).

Answer (score 1):

[Calfskin gloves](https://www.allcockscountry.co.uk/item/Laksen/London-Nubuck-Calfskin-Gloves/EJY) must be in with a chance. They certainly look thin and supple enough.

These white [satin ones](https://www.partydelights.co.uk/Fancy-Dress/ProductDetail.aspx?StockCode=GLOV055) are so cheap that if they don't work you won't have wasted much on them. I reckon they'd need some rosin on the fingertips. If they *do* work you could maybe find a smarter brand.

[Masonic kid gloves](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/242107104/freemasons-masonic-mens-plain-white-kid?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=kid%20leather%20gloves&ref=sr_gallery-1-2&frs=1) look quite fetching, but they'd only work if those seams don't catch and impede your playing, and if the leather is as soft as kid is said to be. Expensive though. (Goats are joining the freemasons now? Who knew?)

Answer (score 1):

I few years ago I hurt my right hand on a mandolin - the kitchen variety, not the instrument - and I had some fairly deep cuts on my fingers.

I had no engagements for a week or two but when I did I wore a thin latex glove over my hand.  It took probably less than five minutes to get used to the slightly different feel but after that I was pretty much unaware of it

So that would be my recommendation.